# Force:recordView and Force:recordEdit broken in Winter '17?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, bug, winter17

All,

I've been developing Lightning Components and get an error in Winter '17 whenever I try to use force:recordView or force:recordEdit:

> Something has gone wrong. afterRender threw an error in
>   'layout://rl-Contact-VIEW-FULL-012700000009b4BAAQ---force_highlights-_1-0-554b47494d493539522f4366576866475665533843413d3d.c'
>   [afterRender threw an error in 'markup://aura:expression' [afterRender
>   threw an error in 'markup://force:pageBlock' [afterRender threw an
>   error in 'markup://aura:html' [afterRender threw an error in
>   'markup://aura:expression' [afterRender threw an error in
>   'markup://force:pageBlockSectionView' [afterRender threw an error in
>   'markup://aura:html' [afterRender threw an error in
>   'markup://aura:html' [afterRender threw an error in
>   'markup://aura:expression' [afterRender threw an error in
>   'markup://force:pageBlockSectionRow' [afterRender threw an error in
>   'markup://aura:html' [afterRender threw an error in
>   'markup://aura:expression' [afterRender threw an error in
>   'markup://force:pageBlockItemView' [afterRender threw an error in
>   'markup://aura:if' [afterRender threw an error in
>   'markup://aura:expression' [afterRender threw an error in
>   'markup://aura:html' [afterRender threw an error in
>   'markup://aura:html' [afterRender threw an error in 'markup://aura:if'
>   [afterRender threw an error in 'markup://aura:html' [afterRender threw
>   an error in 'markup://ui:tooltip' [Assertion Failed!: No cmp wrapper
>   has been set : null]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]] Failing descriptor:
>   {layout://rl-Contact-VIEW-FULL-012700000009b4BAAQ---force_highlights-_1-0-554b47494d493539522f4366576866475665533843413d3d.c}.
>   Please try again.

I've noticed that the root of the error seems to be that ui:tooltip, which the Winter '17 documentation implies may no longer be supported?

[Introducing Base Lightning Components - Bottom of the page](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter17/release-notes/rn_base_lightning_components.htm)

I've tried using them in components/apps with multiple components and I've also tried to use them on their own in an aura:application, just to test them:

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
   <force:recordView aura:id="details" recordId="0034E00000Az9OV"/>
</aura:application>
```

I've found that the component will work if you include type="MINI", but adding/removing "extends=force:slds" doesn't seem to make a difference, so the issue appears to be with the tooltips on the full page.

Can anybody confirm if these components are currently broken?

Comment: Could you please share the code snippet where you referred this event ?

Comment: Absolutely - It's as simple as including it (and only that) on an aura:application. I've included the code snippet in my original question.

Comment: have you tried to put `force:recordView` inside lightning component and use component in lightning application ?

Comment: Yes - I've tried it inside and outside components and I get the same error, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears this has recently been created as a known issue:

[force:recordView throwing errors when layout referencing formula/picklist fields in Lightning app](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000001BcUQAU)